# Thread [main] (Suspended (entry into method main in Game))

Tags: java

When I try to launch my application in debug mode, it just goes straight to the debug panel and says:

```
Thread [main] (Suspended (entry into method main in Game))
    Game.main(String[]) line: 20
```

There are no errors in the code, and I am not exactly sure what I am looking for to fix.

Here is the line that get highlighted in green:

```
JFrame window = new JFrame("Ouroboros");
```

And it is in the Game class:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Game {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        JFrame window = new JFrame("Ouroboros");
        window.add(new GameLauncher());
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setResizable(false);
        window.pack();
        window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        window.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When debugging it pauses where you told it to and continue it you can either hit step in, step over, step out, or resume to continue your program.

There are many tutorials on how to use the debugger.